# jQuery Twitter Widget not populating variables in Safari & IE

Tags: jquery, wordpress, firefox, twitter, safari

A site upon which I'm working is using the following jQuery twitter widget to display feeds:

[Simple jQuery twitter widget](http://blog.gate-advertising.com/post/2011/02/20/Simple-jQuery-twitter-widget.aspx)

Unfortunately, while this widget functions properly on most browsers, the Twitter handles contained within tweets or as part of replies do not display.  Instead, Safari & IE are content to just spit out the variable in the script.

I believe the problem may be in how those browsers are interpreting this function:

```
String.prototype.convertAtToLink = function () {
        return this.replace(/\@[A-Za-z0-9]*/, function (str) {
            var link = "http://twitter.com/{0}";
            link = link.format(str.substr(1));
            var rstr = '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>';
            return rstr.format(link, str);
        });
    };
```

So for example, when in Firefox or another browser, a tweet will appear with RT @username, in Safari it will appear as RT {1}.

Has anyone else encountered this?  Is it tied into the ever-present document.ready issue Safari seems to have?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this small block of code, what I have noticed is the difference here:

```
var rstr = '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>';
```

You have the {0} in double quotes but not the {1}, perhaps changing this to be consistent will allow both variables to properly display.

Comment: James, thank you but I think the previous function shows why your solution won't yield better results:

`String.prototype.format = function () {
            var str = this;
            for (arg in arguments) { str = str.replace("{" + arg + "}", arguments[arg]); }
            return str;
        };`

Also, notice that this is occurring an href string where the double quotes are going to surround the destination URL just as they do in raw HTML.